# RESTful API: DELETE item from a list resource without additional "association resource"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, collections

Simple model: A User can have several friends (=other users).

This could be a representation of a user:

```
{  
"name" : "Chris",  
"friends" : {  
  "href" : "http://example.org/users/32gu/friends",  
  "rel" : "friends",  
  "total" : "2",  
  "elements": [  
   {"name" : "joe", "href" : "http://example.org/users/rzh4028"},  
   {"name" : "susan", "href" : "http://example.org/users/gv5333g"}  
  ]   
}}
```

I want to delete the friendship with Susan. DELETE http://example.org/users/gv5333g would delete Susan...bad.
Something like DELETE http://example.org/users/32gu/friends?id=http://example.org/users/gv5333g wouldn't be that RESTful.

How can I delete a list item without adding a special association resource to my model, like proposed in [Rails RESTful delete in nested resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118259/rails-restful-delete-in-nested-resources)?

Comment: Having a unique ID on both users and friends would simply the code, and then you could do `DELETE http://example.org/users/32gu/friends/rzh4028`

Comment: What property do you give up by adding an association resource?

Comment: Thank you both! I realized that an association resource isn't hat bad. Actually I modeled resources like http://example.org/collection/item but when implementing I got confused. I'll try adding a FriendshipController and use users_friends_url(:userId) as URL.